# Developing a Web Browser in Xcode

Tags: iphone

I'm an iPhone application developer, I'm trying to develop the WEB BROWSER using the xcode, I'm stuck at a point, please tell me, how should I create this application?

Comment: You forgot to give us detailed information about the "point" at which you are stuck. Telling you "how to write a web browser in Xcode" is *much* too broad of a question to be answered here.

Comment: Actually i m unable to get the text which i have given,when i m running the application.........

Comment: please provide the code you have used so that we might be able to understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: Watch this youtube video, https://youtu.be/XWhcnIxrtMk. This is a series video so you will have to wait for new videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes why reinventing the wheel!! use this project - https://github.com/breezeight/IphoneSample_SimpleBrowser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a library already exists for doing so on iPhone. Don't waste your time reinventing (badly) the wheel !

Comment: Actually i m unable to get the text which i have given,when i m running the application......... Can you help me?